# Why is np.unique slower without index return in some cases?

Tags: python, algorithm, numpy, performance

I've noticed that `np.unique` might get slower in some cases if not passing `True` to `return_index` parameter.

```
a = np.ones(shape = (1000, 50), dtype=int)
a[:,-7:] = [10000, -4750, -4750, 95, 95, 95, 95]
arr = np.cumsum(a.ravel())

%timeit np.unique(arr)
%timeit np.unique(arr, return_index=True)
%timeit np.unique(arr, return_index=True, return_inverse=True)
%timeit np.unique(arr, return_index=True, return_inverse=True, return_counts=True)

1.14 ms ± 22.3 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
711 µs ± 6.78 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
955 µs ± 19.3 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
1.3 ms ± 143 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

It doesn't occur usually with other kinds of data. What is happening here?

Answer (score 4):

The difference occurs because the data in your example is *sorted*.  `unique` sorts the data, and when `return_index=True`, a stable merge-sort algorithn is used.  When merge-sort is applied to data that is already sorted, the algorithm will make just one pass through the data, so it is very fast.

For example, in the follow, `arr` is an array of nondecreasing values:

```
In [10]: arr = np.random.randint(0, 3, size=50000).cumsum()

In [11]: arr
Out[11]: array([    1,     3,     4, ..., 49892, 49892, 49894])
```

The default sort algorithm takes almost 8 times as long as the merge-sort:

```
In [12]: %timeit np.sort(arr)
386 µs ± 6.23 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

In [13]: %timeit np.sort(arr, kind='mergesort')
49.5 µs ± 708 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

---

You can see the code that ends up doing the actual work of finding the unique values here: https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/6ff787b93d46cca6d31c370cfd9543ed573a98fc/numpy/lib/arraysetops.py#L320-L361

Comment: This is an excellent answer; perhaps this should also mention that the default sort on ndarrays is a non-stable introsort (quicksort with heapsort fallback), and that a stable sort is *required* for return_index to give the correct answer. It's not specified there why introsort is the default, but the [np.sort()](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.sort.html#numpy.sort) docs do mention that 'mergesort' is actually mapped to either Timsort or Radix sort.

Comment: It is worth noting that Quick-sort is historically considered as a very fast sort compared to others. However, the recent implementation of new sorting technics in Numpy like the Radix sort and the optimization of the other ones cause the choice to be questionable. That being said a very recent change from Intel shown that quick-sort can be much faster (eg. x5) on basic types thanks to AVX-512 (only on recent Intel processors). Quick-sort behave well on random array but not well on sorted arrays. Moreover, it seems the stable sort now check if the array is sorted explaining the timings.

Answer (score 1):

```
arr = np.round(np.random.rand(50000) * 50).astype('int')

%timeit np.unique(arr)
%timeit np.unique(arr, return_index=True)
%timeit np.unique(arr, return_index=True, return_inverse=True)
%timeit np.unique(arr, return_index=True, return_inverse=True, return_counts=True)

274 µs ± 1.01 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
352 µs ± 539 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
397 µs ± 609 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
414 µs ± 555 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Data in your array are all unique. Random data with duplicates didn't reproduce this behavior.
My best guess is NumPy has some optimization for near-all-unique arrays when return_index is specified.

Comment: Ah, I see. Thanks for a clever remark. In my original dataset, count of elements were mostly 0, 1, 2, not just 0, 1. It's still near-all-unique. It would be nice for someone to explain, why algorithms of `np.unique(arr)` and `np.unique(arr, return_index=True)` differs in performance so drastically and how do they run internally.

Comment: You can view the source yourself.  https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/6ff787b93d46cca6d31c370cfd9543ed573a98fc/numpy/lib/arraysetops.py